# ¿Cómo comprobar en java si un archivo es del tipo que indica su extensión?

Tags: java

Por ejemplo si tengo un archivo de vídeo y le cambio la extensión mp4 a txt,  su estructura interna sigue siendo la de un vídeo. Pero cómo podría detectar que sigue siendo un vídeo si la extensión ha sido cambiada. 
He investigado y sé que cada extensión tiene ciertos bytes o cierta estructura que los identifica pero no sé cómo utilizar eso para comprobar lo que dice mi pregunta.

Comment: Deberías leer los primeros bytes del archivo para comprobar si el tipo de extensión es correcta. Puedes hacerlo usando `new FileInputStream(new File("/ruta/a/tu/archivo.extension");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías determinar el MIME TYPE del archivo, mediante [Files.probeContentType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29).

Por ejemplo para un archivo llamado archivo_video.mp4, el [MIME TYPE](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipurpose_Internet_Mail_Extensions) para este tipo de archivo es: `video/mp4`, si cambias la extensión; mediante [Files.probeContentType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29) podrías obtener el tipo y determinar que tipo de contenido es realmente tu archivo:

```
File archivo = new File("C:\\archivos\\archivo_video.txt);
try
{
   String tipodeArchivo = Files.probeContentType(archivo.toPath());
}
catch (IOException ioException)
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + ioException.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Cuidado al usar este método. Según el [tutorial oficial de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/misc.html), se menciona (énfasis mía): "The implementation of this method is **highly platform specific and is not infallible**. The content type is determind by the **platform's default file type detector**. For example, if the detector determines a file's content type to be application/x-java based on the .class extension, it might be fooled." Esto significa que posiblemente este método no funcione tal cual OP espera en Windows.

Comment: Concuerdo, pero dado la multitud de posibilidades en distintos tipos de archivos, no parece una mala idea de empezar con _probeContentType(...)_ y luego comprobar con uno de los métodos de leer el contenido del archivo verificar el resultado.

Comment: @StefanNolde hay reportes de que esto falla mucho en Windows y Mac. Hice una prueba para corroborarlo y, efectivamente, no determina el tipo adecuado en estos OS, usando Java 8. No lo veo como una manera segura de comprobar el MIME type general.

Comment: Buen dato, si las implementaciones son tan poco confiables probablemente es mejor de comprobar directamente el contenido según extensión. Al fin depende del uso - quiero adivinar que tengo en un archivo, o quiero solamente comprobar si la extensión refleja el contenido correctamente.

Comment: si una imagen fue enviada por ajax en formato base64 cómo es posible validar el tipo de archivo con esta forma?? debo decodificar la imagen de nuevo y luego validarla?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes abrir el archivo como *RandomAccessFile* y leer los metadatos del archivo (según las especificaciones del archivo que esperas encontrar).

En el caso de ISO contenedores por ejemplo te toca encontrar el box **ftyp**, que tiene el siguiente formato:

```
<nnnn> - 4 bytes tamaño del box
 ftyp  - 4 bytes ASCII "ftyp" (literalmente)
<cccc> - 4 caracteres código de tipo mayor (por ejemplo "mp41" para mp4 versión 1
<bbbb> - 4 bytes versión
```

el resto de los datos ya es opcional, más información (en ingles) encuentras [aquí](http://www.ftyps.com/what.html), una lista de tipos mayores [aquí](http://ftyps.com/).

Con un archivo video basado en ISO, puedes obtener el tipo mayor así:

```
byte[] tipo = new byte[4];
try{
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("mifile.ext","r");
    file.skipBytes(8); // salta tamaño y "ftyp"
    file.read(tipo);
    String sTipo = new String(tipo);
    System.out.println(String.format("Tipo de archivo: %s", sTipo));
    file.close();
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(Este código no debe ser usado en un sistema productivo, se debe asegurar que los recursos de sistema sean liberados en caso de errores.)